# How do I execute kubelet --resolve-conf?:

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, coredns

I am running into an issue where coredns doesn't seem to be working on my ubuntu instance, I get allot of the following errors from the logs:

```sh
2020-07-16T05:28:36.648Z [INFO] 172.17.0.8:60594 - 29368 "AAAA IN redis-master.cluster.local. udp 44 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd 137 0.000053955s
2020-07-16T05:28:36.650Z [INFO] 172.17.0.8:43585 - 56935 "AAAA IN redis-master. udp 30 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 30 0.001305981s
2020-07-16T05:28:36.650Z [INFO] 172.17.0.8:43585 - 55951 "A IN redis-master. udp 30 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 30 0.001790145s
2020-07-16T05:28:36.803Z [INFO] 172.17.0.11:60313 - 14198 "A IN redis-master.cluster.local. udp 44 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd 137 0.000083909s
2020-07-16T05:28:36.803Z [INFO] 172.17.0.11:60313 - 14670 "AAAA IN redis-master.cluster.local. udp 44 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd 137 0.000078636s
2020-07-16T05:28:36.808Z [INFO] 172.17.0.11:42385 - 5737 "A IN redis-master.svc.cluster.local. udp 48 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd 141 0.000095061s
2020-07-16T05:28:36.808Z [INFO] 172.17.0.11:42385 - 6139 "AAAA IN redis-master.svc.cluster.local. udp 48 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd 141 0.000088591s
2020-07-16T05:28:36.809Z [INFO] 172.17.0.11:47547 - 18338 "A IN redis-master.cluster.local. udp 44 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd 137 0.000077331s
```

I'm hoping that the following paragraph from the docs found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) is the solution:

> Some Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu) use a local DNS resolver by
> default (systemd-resolved). Systemd-resolved moves and replaces
> /etc/resolv.conf with a stub file that can cause a fatal forwarding
> loop when resolving names in upstream servers. This can be fixed
> manually by using kubelet's --resolv-conf flag to point to the correct
> resolv.conf (With systemd-resolved, this is
> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf). kubeadm automatically detects
> systemd-resolved, and adjusts the kubelet flags accordingly.

However, I lack an understanding of how to execute the call to the kubelet. I could use an explanation or code example of how it is supposed to be done.

I am not sure if it is relevant but I am using minikube to test my cluster.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Although original question was about minikube cluster, here is a couple of methods for cluster created by using kubeadm.

First method, using deprecated as of time writing flag --resolv-conf

Source of information https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/#the-kubelet-drop-in-file-for-systemd

- sudo create file `/etc/default/kubelet` with following content

  `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--resolv-conf=path_to_your_resolv.conf`
- restart kubelet service `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`
- recreate CoreDNS pods (restart rollout or delete existing pods)

Second uses KubeletConfiguration object

Source https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-reconfigure/#updating-the-kubeletconfiguration

- edit kubelet config stored in cluster `kubectl edit cm -n kube-system kubelet-config`, look for `resolvConf: ***`
- then download it from cluster to local config on node `kubeadm upgrade node phase kubelet-config`
- restart kubelet service `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`
- recreate CoreDNS pods (restart rollout or delete existing pods)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a conflict with `systemd-resolved` and coredns in your minikube. You can try disabling `systemd-resolved` since you didn't create your cluster using [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/):

- Disable systemd-resolved ⌨

  ```sh
  sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
  sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
  ```
- Put this line in the `[main]` section of your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ⌨:

  ```sh
  dns=default
  ```
- Delete the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` ⌨

  ```sh
  sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- Restart NetworkManager ⌨‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️

  ```sh
  sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
  ```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not change anything, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sounds like you have a different DNS problem

Comment: @Rico I have the same issue but I installed my cluster using kubeadm.. How do I implement the paragraph from the documentation in the question above?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue today, this is what I found - am still validating this answer.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/

Create the following file for every host running kubelet.

/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-docker-opts.conf

```
[Service]
MountFlags=shared
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=--resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, like [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247189/alexander) wrote (the second approach) works, but in my case I didn't have to edit anything in kublet config (it was already pointing to the right `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`) but only do last three steps, so:

- `kubeadm upgrade node phase kubelet-config`
- `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`
- `kubectl -n kube-system delete pod/coredns-<id> ...`

Please bear in mind that this issue is frequent on ubuntu-based nodes, [source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues)